# Prove that if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \ge 2$, then $2^{n + 1} \le 3^n$.

Tags: proof-verification, induction

Prove that if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \ge 2$, then $2^{n + 1} \le 3^n$.

My method:

If $n = 2$, $2^{n + 1} \le 3^n$ then $2^3 \le 3^2$ is $8 \le 9$, which holds for $n = 2$.

$2^{k + 1} \le 3^k$ then $2^{k + 2} \le 3^{k + 1}$. Then 
$2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2^k \lt 3 \cdot 3^k$

$4 \cdot 2^k \lt 3 \cdot 3^k$

Therefore, $4 \cdot 2^k \lt 3 \cdot 3^k$. Hence, $2^{n + 1} \le 3^n$ for $n \ge 2$.

Is there a problem with: $2^{k + 1} \le 3^k$ then $2^{k + 2} \le 3^{k + 1}$ or any other part of this proof?

Comment: It can be strengthened to "$<$"

Comment: Nothing wrong that I see..although you may want to organize it to better follow standard induction arguments.

Comment: @Bey would you have any advice for going about that?

Comment: @Matt sure...like I said, your proof looks fine, but it would be helpful if you first established $2^{k+1}\leq 3^k \implies  2^{k+2}\leq 3^{k+1}$ then noted that it is true when $n=2$, then proceed to the conclusion via induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is easy:

- If $k=2$, we know that $2^{k+1} = 2^3 = 8 \leq 9 = 3^2 = 3^k$. Then, it is true.
- We assume that it is also true for $k=n$, then we assume that $2^{n+1} \leq 3^{n}$
- We want to see that it is true if $k = n+1$:

$2^{k+1} = 2^{n+2} = 2^{n+1} \cdot 2$

We assumed before $2^{n+1} \leq 3^{n}$, then

$2^{k+1} = 2^{n+1} \cdot 2 \leq 3^{n} \cdot 2 \leq 3^{n} \cdot 3 = 3^{n+1}=3^k \rightarrow 2^{k+1} \leq 3^k$

What we do is:

- We prove that it is true for $k=2$
- We prove that if it is true for $k=n$, then it is also true for $k=n+1$

Therefore, it is true for $k=3$ because it is true for $k=2$. It is true for $k=4$ because it is true for $k=3$...

Comment: please do not add promotional links to the answer. you can add it to your users profile page

Answer (score 1):

Formal proof by induction.

---

**First, show that this is true for $n=2$:**

$2^{2+1}<3^2$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$2^{n+1}<3^n$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$2^{n+2}=$

$2\cdot\color\red{2^{n+1}}<$

$2\cdot\color\red{3^n}<$

$3\cdot3^n=$

$3^{n+1}$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.